# Is there any slack API to update profile information?

Tags: slack-api, slack

Hi I would like to update profile information of my slack account using API.
I don't find any API on their documentation. Do they have any API to update profile information?

See the screenshot http://screencast.com/t/f7eoAKT0Yy

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do.

But it's an undocumented API method. It's called `users.profile.set`. So far I used it to change first- and last name, but other attributes should work too.

The basic syntax is:

```
users.profile.set?token=XXX&user=U12345678&profile=NEWPROFILE
```

`NEWPROFILE` is a placeholder for the new profile for the user in JSON format, but you only need to specify the attributes you want to change, e.g. `profile={"first_name":"John"}` will change the first name to John.

Check out my documentation on [github](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc) for details and other undocumented methods in the Slack API.

**Update November 2018**

- [user.profile.set](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set) is now an official API method. However, you
  need to be on a paid team to use it for other users (not yourself).
  Although you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094180/changing-status-of-other-users-on-a-free-plan-slack/53102052#53102052) for a workaround.
- [users.setPhoto](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPhoto) will allow you to change the profile picture. but
  only for your own user / token.

Comment: No, not yet. But I have put this up as question on Slack. Hopefully someone knows how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449567/can-i-use-the-slack-api-to-set-the-profile-picture

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have any API for this.http://screencast.com/t/dmBImpJfkXu

Comment: They now have a method to update the profile of a slack user. Please see may answer for details.