# Can I use the Slack API to set the profile picture?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am running a Slack team for a gaming community. My users all have avatars in the game and I am already using the Slack API to automatically set their Slack user name to their in-game name, so its easier for people to be recognized.

In addition I would also like to automatically set their profile picture in Slack with their avatar picture from the game. However I could not figure out a way to do it, so my question is can it be done and if yes, how?

My current starting point is the undocumented API method `users.profile.set` which allows me to set the profile of a user (see below for an example of a user profile). So far I've been able to modify:

- first_name
- last_name
- title
- phone
- skype

The user profile also contains the URL to the profile picture, but I was so far not able to change it. I tried external URLs, and URLs of images already uploaded on Slack.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.profile.set.md) to my documentation of the "undocumented" Slack API method `users.profile.set` with all options that I could figure out so far.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

---

**Update November 2017**

In the meantime Slack has added a new API method called [`users.setPhoto`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPhoto) for setting profile photos. However, this new method does not solve this question, because it only works for your own user (or more precisely the user you have an access token for, e.g. you not specify another `user ID`).

I am looking for a way to change the profile pictures of all users on my Slack team by a Slack app / bot.

---

Example of a user profile:

```
{
id: "U12345678",
team_id: "T12345678",
name: "erik.kalkoken",
deleted: false,
status: null,
color: "9f69e7",
real_name: "Erik Kalkoken",
tz: "America/Chicago",
tz_label: "Central Daylight Time",
tz_offset: 3600,
profile: {
avatar_hash: "XXX",
first_name: "Erik",
last_name: "Kalkoken",
title: "",
phone: "",
skype: "",
image_24: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_24.jpg",
image_32: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_32.jpg",
image_48: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_48.jpg",
image_72: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_72.jpg",
image_192: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_192.jpg",
image_512: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_512.jpg",
image_1024: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_512.jpg",
image_original: "https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-03-19/XXX_original.jpg",
real_name: "Erik Kalkoken",
real_name_normalized: "Erik Kalkoken",
email: "test@email.com"
},
is_admin: false,
is_owner: false,
is_primary_owner: false,
is_restricted: false,
is_ultra_restricted: false,
is_bot: false,
has_2fa: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the profile picture API is available yet. I read a while back that it was on their TODO list.

Comment: Yes, that that might be the case. However I read the same statement about other "undocumented" API method that do actually exist. So my hope is that method for changing the profile picture exists and that someone has figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

After messing around with it for a little, it's possible to use the undocumented `users.setPhoto` endpoint:

```sh
curl https://slack.com/api/users.setPhoto \
    -F "token=<removed>" \
    -F "image=@/path/to/image.jpg"
```

Unfortunately it will resize your avatar which removes the ability to upload animated gifs.

Comment: That looks really promising. Unfortunately I have problems setting a new image. always get the "no_image" error. Can you please be more specific how the image parameter is defined? Maybe give an example? thanks.

Comment: Also should there not be a user parameter as well?

Comment: The `@` is required (cURL specific) and the path _must_ be absolute. The user that generated the token is the default user & I didn't explore much further about setting other user profile images. If the authors of this endpoint kept similar parameters across the API, you may be able to specify a user with the same `user` field used in the documented `users.profile.set` endpoint.

Comment: Slack added a new method called "setPhoto" which allows to set the profile picture. However, it only works for the current user, so it does not really solve the purpose of this question.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Did you ever get around the `no_image` error?

Comment: @0xcaff no I did not. and have not tried in a while

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using Jay Querie's method.
The two difference was I gave the full path and I put the image first.
So in my case:

```
curl https://slack.com/api/users.setPhoto -F "image=@C:\Users\name\Pictures\dojocat.jpg" -F "token=xxxx-123-123-123-123"
```

Originally when I was using gitbash to run the curl and it was searching for the image in the directory where my gitbash was installed / being executed. So if I put the dojocat.jpg next to my gitbash executable it would would have found it.