# Slack OAuth token expiration

Tags: slack, slack-api

I had a couple of followup questions in reference to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102052/6280556):

1. Does the user access token obtained using [OAuth flow](https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth#flow) expire in a given time period by default? It does mention [here](https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth#exchanging_code) that they never expire but wanted to confirm once.
2. [Authorization codes](https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth#redirect_users) required to get user access token expires in 10minutes after issuance. In such a scenario user will have to be redirected again?
3. If the user either uninstalls the application or revokes the token and say decides to reinstall the application later.
   In this scenario is the user access token now different from what it was before the app reinstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct, access tokens don't expire *unless* you have enabled [token rotation](https://api.slack.com/authentication/rotation).
2. Yes, in that case the user would have to be redirected again.
3. Yes, once a user uninstalls the app and the token is revoked, that token will never be useable again. When the same user re-installs the app a new access token is provided.